# How to use maps in c++?

Tags: c++, maps

I have read about maps in c++ and I know their role , but I don't know how to use them.
If I have n numbers and to each of them is assigned a number of apples (for example "x1=5" has 4 apples, "x2=-2" has 7 etc) how do I sort the numbers and accordingly sum up the number of apples,so that x1 will still have the same number of apples although its position in the sorted data structure (which I suppose is map ) will change?

Comment: `std::map` sorts the data by key. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map for example code and to get started.

Comment: @RSahu thank you for your response. According to the above example, i need to sort the x-s , and then sum up the number of apples each of them contain .

Comment: The code to do that is very simple. You should be able to do that yourself.

Comment: @RSahu yes , but how to assign the number of apples to each x which is in a certain position and then sum up the apples accordingly although the positions of x-s have changed ?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure i understand your question but here you go :

```
std::map<int, int> map;
map[5] = 4; // x1 = 5 has 4 apples.
map[-2] = 7; // x2 = -2 has 7 apples.
//to find the value of x1 : 
int x1 = map[5];
```

Items in a `std::map` are always sorted by key so you don't have to sort them manually.

Comment: thank you for your response. What i mean is that to every x1=5 , x2=-89 , x3=100 is assigned  a number of apples so : x1=5 has got 57 apples for example, x2=-89 has got 33 and so on. The values that x-s are equal to , show just the positions of the x.

Comment: I still don't understand, what are x1, x2, ... supposed to represent ? Maps associate a value to another, so if you want to say 'the value 5 has 18 apples and the value -7 has 42 apples' that's what they do : 5 and -7 being the keys.

Comment: X1=5 has 57 apples ---> the shop (for example) in position 5 , has 57 apples. Then i need to sum up the apples.

Comment: So you can just iterate over all the elements in the map and sum them, what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The summation after assigning the map.

```
std::map<int,int>::iterator it;
int total = 0;

for(it i = map.begin(); i != map.end(); ++i)
{
    total+=it->second;
}
```